# matlab script to c++

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to implement this person's code: http://iris.lib.neu.edu/civil_eng_theses/30/ but I can not generate a working executable in visual studio because I am missing 2 files: myoutput.cpp and PrintTimeReferencedVariable.cpp.  I am unclear if the Matlab builder is supposed to generate them or I write them.

The myoutput.cpp is supposed to be a C++ file that does essentially a dlmwrite.  It is used as follows:

```
function [] = Output_01(FileName, FileNameLenght, OutputData, OutputSize1, OutputSize2)
coder.inline('never')
coder.ceval( 'myoutput', FileName, FileNameLenght, OutputData, OutputSize1, OutputSize2);            
end
% %% Matlab Version: to run the model in Matlab uncomment below, comment above
% function [] = Output_01(FileName, FileNameLenght, OutputData, OutputSize1, OutputSize2)
% dlmwrite(FileName, OutputData,'-append','coffset',0,'delimiter','\t','precision','%6.6G')
% precision = 4;
% disp( num2str( OutputData,precision))
% end
```

Where the commented out is the matlab version of the file and the top is what is built into C++.  The files are supposed to write to the directory: C:\matlab-results-from-cpp.

The PrintTimeReferencedVariable.cpp looks like a date function that should do:

```
% Date = datestr(now, 'yyyy-mm-dd-HH-MM-SS' );
%% Matlab Version: to run the model in Matlab uncomment above, comment below
Date = '2012-09-16-09-19-20';
coder.ceval('PrintTimeReferencedVariable', coder.wref(Date));
```

Any insight into this would be much help.  I'm still waiting to hear back from the author but it would still be helpful to hear all of your input as this is my first time in C++ and building projects in Matlab.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the text is pretty clear on what you do, though I can understand the confusion not coming from a C++ background:

> 5)
>   “Project Settings ”adjustments: Open ‘More settings’,then in ‘All Settings’ tab, choose for ‘Language’ C ++; In “Speed” tab mark only “Saturate on integer overflow”, unmark everything else; in “Custom Code ” tab, copy and paste the first lines the functions “myoutput.cpp” and “PrintTimeReferencedVariable.cpp”, followed by semicolon or see below the text:

```
void PrintTimeReferencedVariable (char * DateOut); 

void myoutput(const char* _filename, int fileNameLen, double* data, int n, int m);
```

So you create the files "myoutput.cpp" and "PrintTimeReferencedVariable.cpp".  Copy and paste the code into the respective cpp files.  Then add the prototype(the second quote) to your header or at the top of those files.

Comment: I do all that but then I get this error:                        Output_01.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl myoutput(char const *,int,double *,int,int)" (?myoutput@@YAXPBDHPANHH@Z)          idk :(

Comment: Looks like you're not declaring the prototype correctly.  I can help more if you post the cpp code.